# Edición de tablas bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap

Acabo de montar una aplicación y ya está en uso en mi compañía, me reportaron que en ciertas ocasiones, si se dan muchos clics a una parte de la tabla, les permite agregar columnas y filas.

Estuve probando esto, pero no me pasa a mi, de hecho hasta pueden arrastrar las columnas y ponerlas en otro lugar que no corresponde.

Estos casos son especiales, no aparecen siempre. Solo cuando la gente es destructora 3>:) . Me percate que este problema solo pasa con Mozilla Firefox, con Chrome no pasó esto.

Espero me puedan ayudar a quitar esta opción. Digo: no perjudica la operación, pero quiero saber por que pasa.

Este es el código de la tabla:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
           <tr>
                <th>Cuenta</th>
                <th>Caso de negocio</th>
                <th>No. de orden</th>
                <th>Fecha requerida</th>
                <th>Titular</th>
                <th>Motivo de la orden</th>
                <th>HUB</th>
                <th>Usuario creador de la OS</th>
                <th>Resultado de la llamada</th>
                <th>Comentarios</th>
                <th>Seguimiento</th>
           </tr>';
if(mysqli_num_rows($resulta) > 0)
{
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resulta))
 {
      if($row["tkc"]==""||$row["tkc"]=="#N/A")
      {
            $output.='<tr>';
      }
      else
      {
        $output.='<tr class="info">';
      }
      $output.='
                <td style="width:4%;" class="account" data-id1="'.$row["id_bo"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["account"].'</td>
                <td style="width:7%;" class="cn" data-id2="'.$row["id_bo"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["cn"].'</td>
                <td style="width:7%;">'.$row["order_no"].'</td>
                <td style="width:3%;">'.$row["required_date"].'</td>
                <td style="width:7%;">'.ucwords(strtolower($row["costumer"])).'</td>
                <td style="width:6%;">'.$row["sub_type"].'</td>
                <td style="width:1%;">'.$row["hub"].'</td>
                <td style="width:7%;" class="user_creator" data-id3="'.$row["id_bo"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["user_creator"].'</td>
                <td style="width:17%;">
                  <select style="height:50%; "class="form-control inputstyle result" data-id4="'.$row["id_bo"].'">
                    <option ';if($row["result"]==0){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="0">Selecciona una opción</option>
                    <option ';if($row["result"]==1){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="1">Continua la falla después de procesos</option>
                    <option ';if($row["result"]==2){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="2">Servicio ok sin procesos se cancela TC</option>
                    <option ';if($row["result"]==3){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="3">Se cancela por antigüedad (4 Dias)</option>
                    <option ';if($row["result"]==4){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="4">Se realiza TS y Servicio Ok, se cancela TC</option>
                    <option ';if($row["result"]==5){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="5">OS completa</option>
                    <option ';if($row["result"]==6){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="6">No contesta/Contestadora/Tel Ocupado/Equivocado</option>
                    <option ';if($row["result"]==7){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="7">Se cancela OS fue generada en afectación</option>
                    <option ';if($row["result"]==8){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="8">OS cancelada</option>
                    <option ';if($row["result"]==9){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="9">Cliente no quiere cancelar el TC</option>
                    <option ';if($row["result"]==10){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="10">No puede informar sobre el servicio/No conoce el problema</option>
                    <option ';if($row["result"]==11){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="11">Cliente no apoya con procesos se confirma visita técnica</option>
                    <option ';if($row["result"]==12){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="12">Se cancela OS por saldo vencido</option>
                    <option ';if($row["result"]==13){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="13">Se cancela OS, cliente no acepta visita</option>
                    <option ';if($row["result"]==14){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="14">Se cancela OS cuenta aplica para SWAT(RxMer, Nav. Lenta)</option>
                  </select>
                  </td>
                <td class="coments" data-id5="'.$row["id_bo"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["coments"].'</td>
                <td style="width:17%;">
                <select style="height:50%; "class="form-control inputstyle tracking" data-id6="'.$row["id_bo"].'">
                  <option ';if($row["tracking"]==0){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' disabled="disabled">Selecciona una opción</option>
                  <option ';if($row["tracking"]==1){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="1">Ticket en mesa de ayuda</option>
                  <option ';if($row["tracking"]==2){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="2">Ticket en segundo nivel</option>
                  <option ';if($row["tracking"]==3){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="3">Problema conocido</option>
                  <option ';if($row["tracking"]==4){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="4">Solicita llamada por la mañana</option>
                  <option ';if($row["tracking"]==5){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="5">Solicita llamada por la tarde</option>
                  <option ';if($row["tracking"]==6){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="6">Falla general en proceso</option>
                  <option ';if($row["tracking"]==7){$output.= 'selected';} $output.=' value="7">Seguimiento completado</option>
                </select>
              </td>
           </tr>
</table>
 </div>
```

Aquí una imagen de lo que está pasando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el fin de optimizar la página bajé las librerías, pero la funcionalidad sigue siendo la misma. (Lo bajé de las páginas oficiales).

En cuanto a CSS:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

En JS:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hola **Alberto** bastante extraño, que *librerias* mas de css y javascript está utilizando? puede pegar el resultado en HTML no el código en PHP. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es porque Firefox detecta de esa forma el contenteditable, para solucionar esto solo agrega este script en el head o en un archivo .js o donde quieras pero que sea lo primero que se cargue

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        document.execCommand("enableInlineTableEditing", null, false);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Funcionó perfecto! Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Intenta quitando el primer script de Jquery:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Cuando agregas dos veces la libreria de jquery se puede presentar una serie de problemas. La unica diferencia es que la versión ".min" es la versión minificada del archivo, la funcionalidad es la misma.
¿Tienes mas detalles de tu problema?